# qucs capacitor simulation

Tags: capacitor, ac, simulation, qucs

I was playing with qucs and noticed that capacitors are not simulated as I expected. I designed simplest circuit that illustrates that case.

AC Source: 2 Hz (2 times a a second)
Capacitor: 1pF 
Simulation: 1 second

I expected to see different graphs on Probe 1 and Probe 2 BUT they are same.

[image]

Is it correct results? If not how do I get it to show correct results?
.. or how should I use qucs to simulate such circuit? (e.g. should I put some resistors)

**PS** I added 10 MOhm in parallel and it worked. Thanks @DaveTweed

[image]

Comment: Why do you think they should be different? How much current is flowing through the capacitor, and how much voltage is across it? (Hint: If you want to simulate how a real voltmeter or oscilloscope would behave, put a 10Mohm resistor in parallel with PR2.)

Comment: What results are "correct" depends on what circuit you want to simulate. If you want to simulate a circuit with resistors (or with a resistive load), put resistors. If you want to simulate a circuit without resistors, don't put resistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the "probe" or voltmeter PR2 has [(by design)](https://github.com/Qucs/qucs/blob/master/qucs-core/src/components/vprobe.cpp) an extremely high input resistance. Even the tiniest current (in fact no current at all) flowing through the capacitor will "move the needle" of the meter.

For a more practical result, place a **1M resistor over the terminals of PR2**, and change capacitor C1 to 80nF.